# Using DateTime.ParseExact throws format exception

Tags: vb.net

I know the question is really asked often, but I can't find the solution to my problem. My code is

```
Public Function ConvertFacebookDateToNETDate(Instant As String, Format As String) As Date
    'Dim UTCOffset As New Integer
    'UTCOffset = Instant.Substring(Instant.IndexOf("UTC+") + 4, 2)

    Dim MyDateTime As DateTime
    MyDateTime = New DateTime()
    MyDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(Instant, Format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    'MyDateTime = MyDateTime.AddHours(-1 * UTCOffset)
    Return MyDateTime
End Function

ConvertFacebookDateToNETDate("Friday, May 9, 2014 at 9:48am UTC+02", "dddd, MMMM d, yyyy at h:mtt UTCK")
```

What is going wrong here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with the data format

- The `t` in `at` is interpreted as the short form of `tt`, i.e. the first character of AM/PM designator. You need to escape it to specify that it's a literal character.
- The specifier for time zone offset in hours is `z`, not `K`.

So:

```
ConvertFacebookDateToNETDate("Friday, May 9, 2014 at 9:48am UTC+02", "dddd, MMMM d, yyyy' at 'h:mtt UTCz")
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things (all the info comes from [there](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

- In your format you put `"at"` but `"t"` if a format specifier so you have to escape it `"a\t"` or put it between literal delimiter `"'at'"`
- The `"K"` format specifier for a DateTime with Kind local (a `"±XX"`) needs to be `"±XX:XX"` so you have to either pass a Date string with that pattern or use `"zz"` format specifier instead of `"K"`